# jQuery trigger does not execute custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to subscribe an html element within a page to events. Once such an event is triggered, the html element should display error information to the user. These error triggers will be triggered within AJAX call error functions. However, once such an error happens, the customer event is never triggered. Here is the code for the html observer:

```
$(function(){
  $('#errorNotification').on('/nofitications/error', function(event, message){
    console.log('event triggered');
    var errorElement = $('#errorNotification');
    var errorTitle = $('#errorNotification #title');
    var errorMessage = $('#errorNotification #message');
    $(errorElement).addClass('alert-error');
    errorTitle.html(message.title);
    errorMessage.html(message.content);
  });
});
```

And here is the code from the AJAX call that should trigger the event:

```
.finally(function () {
     $('#errorNotification').trigger('/notifications/error', {title: 'Fehler', content: 'content'});
 });
```

Even though the finally function does get executed after the AJAX call finishes, the custom event is never executed.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Typo : line 2 first snippet : `$('#errorNotification').on('/nofitications/error' ...` should be `noTiFications` not `nofitications` ?

Comment: @zimmi, make it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo : line 2 first snippet : `$('#errorNotification').on('/nofitications/error'` ... should be `noTiFications` not `nofitications`

Comment: I have been looking at this screen for too many long hours today. Thanks for the quick pointer.

Comment: @LuisDelgado You're welcome ! We all have to go through this kind of things :-)